# Ngx Extended PDF Viewer - PDF Form Fields

Tags: angular, form-fields, pdf-form, ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

I am using ngx extended pdf viewer to show my form in my application. the problem is i need form data on the initial load of the component in ngx i can get the form data only when i change the form field
by using (formDataChange) , i need to do some validation on form fields so i need the form data initally is there any way to get that in ngx pdf service

i try ngx pdf service formdata change method to get the form data if any change occurs i try to use the same method when the component oninit but i got error ,my expectation is i need form data of the pdf form on the initial load

Comment: (pdfLoaded)="onEvent('pdfLoaded', $event)"

Comment: (pdfLoaded)="onEvent('pdfLoaded', $event)"
after try using this i can get the form data by using this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.